# AnalysisException using when in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("joe", 34), ("luisa", 22)], ["name", "age"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("joe", 88), ("luisa", 99)], ["name", "age"])
```

I want to update the age when the names match. So I thought using a when() would work.

```
df.withColumn("age", F.when(df.name == df2.name, df2.age)).otherwise(df.age)
```

but this results in this error:

```
AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) name#181,age#182L missing from name#177,age#178L in operator !Project [name#177, CASE WHEN (name#177 = name#181) THEN age#182L END AS age#724L]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: name,age. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;
```

how do resolve this? because when i print the when statement i see this:

```
Column<'CASE WHEN (name = name) THEN age ELSE age END'>
```

Comment: you'll need to do a join operation to use that column before the case when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "update age", I assume you want latest/greatest age:

```py
df \
  .join(df2, how="inner", on="name") \
  .withColumn("updated_age", F.greatest(df2.age, df.age)) \
  .select("name", F.col("updated_age").alias("age"))

[Out]:
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|  joe| 88|
|luisa| 99|
+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a join :

```py
df.join(df2, how="left", on="name").withColumn("age", F.coalesce(df2.age, df.age))
```